# EntityFramework ObjectContext Refresh issue

Tags: entity-framework-4, observablecollection

I have DataContext.Refresh Method:

```
  public void RefreshDataSource()
    {
        _entities.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins,Departments);
    }
```

And observable collection:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Department> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            if (_departments == null && _entities != null)
            {
                _entities.Departments.Include("Drivers").ToArray();
                _departments = new EntityObservableCollection<Department>(_entities.Departments);
            }
            return _departments;
        }
    }
```

If i update records outside context i see only changed records but can't see inserted and removed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because `Refresh` doesn't look for new records. It takes records you already have and updates them with current values. It also probably doesn't handle deleted records especially if you use `ClientWins` strategy which takes your state as more important.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But how can i handle inserted and deleted records? Maybe it is present standard mechanism?

Comment: If you want to handle inserted and deleted records you must execute the query used to get departments again and configure query / object set to use `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges` (equivalent to `StoreWins`) or `MergeOption.PreserveChanges` (equivalent to `ClientWins`).